# Group by using MAX()

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I am trying get the most recent end date (`ProjectsTasksEndDate`) from the task's project and group by it without success. Bellow are the SQLFiddle. Any suggestions?

PS.: The commented select was a base to build the select I am trying to get to.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68cce/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects 
(
  id int identity primary key, 
  ProjectID varchar(20),
  ProjectStartDate date,
  ProjectEndDate date
 );

CREATE TABLE ProjectsTasks 
(
  id int identity primary key, 
  ProjectID varchar(20), 
  ProjectsTasksStartDate date,
  ProjectsTasksEndDate date
 );

INSERT INTO Projects
(ProjectID, ProjectStartDate, ProjectEndDate)
VALUES
('1', '2015-01-05', '2015-04-08'),
('2', '2015-01-06', '2015-07-20'),
('3', '2015-02-05', '2015-07-22'),
('4', '2015-03-05', '2015-08-08'),
('5', '2015-03-05', '2015-09-18'),
('6', '2015-04-05', '2015-10-02'),
('7', '2016-07-05', '2016-11-20');

INSERT INTO ProjectsTasks
(ProjectID, ProjectsTasksStartDate, ProjectsTasksEndDate)
VALUES
('1', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-10'),
('1', '2015-01-06', '2015-02-20'),
('1', '2015-02-05', '2015-03-20'),
('1', '2015-03-01', '2015-03-02'),
('1', '2015-01-05', '2015-04-08'),
('2', '2015-06-01', '2015-06-20'),
('3', '2015-12-20', '2015-12-21');
```

**Query 1**:

```
/*
SELECT
    YEAR (Projects.ProjectEndDate) AS [Year],
    MONTH (Projects.ProjectEndDate) AS [Month],
    COUNT (*) AS [Total]
FROM
    Projects
GROUP BY
    YEAR (Projects.ProjectEndDate),
    MONTH (Projects.ProjectEndDate)
*/


SELECT
    YEAR (MAX(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)) AS [Year],
    MONTH (MAX(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)) AS [Month],
    COUNT (*) AS [Total]
FROM  Projects 
RIGHT JOIN ProjectsTasks  
  ON Projects.ProjectID = ProjectsTasks.ProjectID
GROUP BY  YEAR (ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate),
          MONTH (ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)
```

**[Expected Results]**:

```
| Year | Month | Total |
|------|-------|-------|
| 2015 |     4 |     1 |
| 2015 |     6 |     1 |
| 2015 |    12 |     1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intetion correctly, you could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
     [Year]  = YEAR(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)
    ,[Month] = MONTH(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)
    ,[Total] = COUNT (*)
FROM  Projects 
RIGHT JOIN ProjectsTasks  
  ON Projects.ProjectID = ProjectsTasks.ProjectID
GROUP BY YEAR(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate),
         MONTH(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/UFCH71422)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [Year],[Month],[Total]
FROM (
  SELECT  ProjectsTasks.ProjectID
    ,[Year]  = YEAR(MAX(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate))
    ,[Month] = MONTH(MAX(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate))
    ,[Total] = COUNT (*)
  FROM  Projects 
  RIGHT JOIN ProjectsTasks  
    ON Projects.ProjectID = ProjectsTasks.ProjectID
  GROUP BY ProjectsTasks.ProjectID,
           YEAR(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate),
           MONTH(ProjectsTasks.ProjectsTasksEndDate)
) s
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProjectID 
                           ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo 2`](http://rextester.com/EZO84786)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Year ║ Month ║ Total ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 2015 ║     4 ║     1 ║
║ 2015 ║     6 ║     1 ║
║ 2015 ║    12 ║     1 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: I just updated the original post. I am spectating only one row, in this case, because I am looking for the most recent task end date. Thanks for your tme.

Comment: Well, This was just an example. In the real case I can't use TOP 1, because there will be other projects, instead of only one.

Comment: @Khrys Please prepare larger sample and desired resultset.

Comment: Ok, I tested it, and I tried to see of the Total could get more than 1. So I updated with this link: http://rextester.com/LYX23686.
See there is 2 lines for month 11. It should be only one line and Total = 2. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Khrys But they are with different projects 3 and 4. Aggregation is based on projectID, that is why you get 2 rows with 1 at each.

Comment: I see, but my objective are only Year, Month, no matter what project is. Thanks for your help.